# The .env file does not come to some external laravel projects, how do we get it again?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

The .env file does not come to external laravel projects, how do we get it again in vscode?
getting .env file to vscode. why these laravel projects not coming to .env file? what is the reason for that, i want to get .env file.

Comment: If you provide projects over (for example) git/GitHub, `.env` file is excluded from pushing to code repository. All list of files and directories excluded you can check in `.gitignore` file. And it should stay that way with reason. You would need to create .env file manually where ever is needed. If I didn't misunderstend your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try these commands:

1. `cp .env.example .env`
   This will help to copy `.env.example` file as `.env`
2. `php artisan key:generate`
   This will generate a key for laravel project